# How to list all results of probability experiment in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Just stuck on how to list all my results in one matrix. As of right now I only get one result from my 100 repetitions. Is there one line I can add to the end which would allow me to get the results from all 100 repetitions?

```
N=1000; %Number of Die Rolls
nreps=100;
count=zeros(1,N+1);     

for n=1:nreps
     n_3H = 0; %count the number of occurrences of the pattern HHH
      flipStates = randi([1, 2], 1, N)  %code to toss a coin N times
      for i=3:N
        if  all(flipStates(i-2:i) == [1,1,1])%condition that the pattern HHH appears at position (i-2,i-1,i)
            n_3H = n_3H+1;
        end
      end
     %ADD CODE TO LIST ALL RESULTS IN COUNT VARIABLE
end
```

Comment: Did you try assigning the value to an entry in `count`? `count(n) = n_3H`?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had count(i,:)=n_3H